# could not find a match for std::find (Codegear C++ 2007)

Tags: c++, borland-c++

The following code makes with no problem in BDS 2006.
In Codegear RAD studio 2007, make produces error.

I search and guess it's related to type casting but found no clues.
The purpose of codes is to check if one value exists in an array.
Any advice is appreciated.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum E_TRIGGER_MODE
{
    TRIGGER_MODE_SINGLE = 0,
    TRIGGER_MODE_NORMAL,
    TRIGGER_MODE_AUTO,
    TRIGGER_MODE_CONTINUOUS
};

static enum E_TRIGGER_MODE eMode[] = 
    { TRIGGER_MODE_AUTO, TRIGGER_MODE_NORMAL, 
    TRIGGER_MODE_SINGLE, TRIGGER_MODE_CONTINUOUS };


namespace Utils
{
    template<class Type, class Element, int n>
    bool in_group(const Type value, const Element (&array)[n])
    {
        return std::find(array, array+n, value) != array+n;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    int mode = TRIGGER_MODE_AUTO;
    if (Utils::in_group(mode, eMode))
        cout << "in group OK\n";
    else
        cout << "in group FAIL\n";
}
```

error message:

```
[BCC32 Error] File3.cpp(44): E2285 Could not find a match for 'std::find<_InIt,_Ty>(const E_TRIGGER_MODE *,const E_TRIGGER_MODE *,const int)'
```

Edit:

The code is from a package that was created using BDS2006 with a .bdsproj file. Current version of RAD studio(10.x) cannot open this project file without problem. That's why I try RAD studio 2007

Comment: A quick reminder that today's date is July 24, **2020**... in order words, you are working with a _very_ dated compiler, and `std::find` was probably introduced in C++11.

Comment: [Works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B0kZqJFzr05r8LCJ) after fixing `main()`.

Comment: @dandan78 Nope, `std::find` existed from C++03 or C++98

Comment: It looks like an issue with compiler, your code is correct (`*array` is of type `E_TRIGGER_MODE`, which is convertible to `int`). Does your compiler provide no further info on this error? What overloads did it try? You can try casting, but... at this point you should really get a modern compiler.

Comment: Let me explain why I use such an old compiler. The code is from a package that was created using BDS2006 with a .bdsproj file. Current version of RAD studio(10.x) cannot open this project file. That's why I try RAD studio 2007.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you for your hint.

Comment: @dream why not simply update the project?  Create a new project in 10.x, add the existing source files to it as needed, and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find an `int` in an array of `E_TRIGGER_MODE` enums.  The 3rd parameter of `std::find()` needs to be compatible with the type returned by dereferencing the 1st parameter.  The compiler won't allow you to implicitly convert an `int` to an `enum`, so you need to use an explicit type-cast when passing your `int` to `Utils::in_group()`.

Since the type being search for needs to be compatible with the type of the array's elements, I would suggest getting rid of the `Type` template parameter altogether, it serves no real purpose.  Use the `Element` template parameter instead for the `value` function parameter.  If you try to pass in a type that is not compatible, the compiler will fail at the call site of `in_group()` rather than at the call site of `std::find()`.  That is more useful for users.

Also, you should pass the `value` parameter by const reference.  `std::find()` takes that parameter by const reference anyway, so there is no point in passing it into `Utils::in_group()` by value.

With that said, try this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

enum E_TRIGGER_MODE
{
    TRIGGER_MODE_SINGLE = 0,
    TRIGGER_MODE_NORMAL,
    TRIGGER_MODE_AUTO,
    TRIGGER_MODE_CONTINUOUS
};

static E_TRIGGER_MODE eMode[] = 
    { TRIGGER_MODE_AUTO, TRIGGER_MODE_NORMAL, 
    TRIGGER_MODE_SINGLE, TRIGGER_MODE_CONTINUOUS };

namespace Utils
{
    template<class Element, int n>
    bool in_group(const Element &value, const Element (&array)[n])
    {
        const Element *end = array + n;
        return std::find(array, end, value) != end;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    int mode = TRIGGER_MODE_AUTO;
    if (Utils::in_group(static_cast<E_TRIGGER_MODE>(mode), eMode))
        cout << "in group OK\n";
    else
        cout << "in group FAIL\n";
}
```

Otherwise, simply don't use an `int` to begin with, use an `enum` instead:

```cpp
E_TRIGGER_MODE mode = TRIGGER_MODE_AUTO;
if (Utils::in_group(mode, eMode))
```